# Pick a .bin file via Intent.createChooser in Android

Tags: android, binaryfiles, filepicker

Running this code allows a user to select a file:

```
private int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 3456;
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
chooseFile.setType("file/*");
chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

How can I adapt this code to ensure *only .bin files* can be selected?

I have currently two problems:

- .bin files are shown as *folders*, (empty folders)
- I don't know how to restrict the file picker to only files with a specific extension.

---

**[update]**
Weirdly enough, when trying this code on another Android 10 phone, no file can be selected.

When adapting the code snippet to:

```
private int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 3456;
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

the selection of a file with extension .bin *is* possible, but only on that second phone. On the first phone, binary files are still presented as empty folders.

---

**[update]**

To augment the confusion, removing the call to `createChooser` seems to have no effect, on both my phones. Or the other way around, adding the call seems to have no effect.

```
private int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 3456;
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Which makes me wonder, what that call is supposed to be doing?

Can somebody make sense of this?

Comment: If you mean file names with extension .bin then they are selectable files here.

Comment: Yes, I mean files with extension .bin. Does "here" apply to you phone? Here on my phone (Android 10) they are shown as empty folders.

Comment: Not on 10. Not on 11. Strange story.

Comment: Did you use the exact same code?

Comment: I dont know. I think that `*/*` is used or without type. And probably without chooser.

Comment: Well, I got my hands on a second phone, and indeed, results are different (better) there. Which is not encouraging, actually. See the updated question.

Comment: Try without chooser too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233051/discussion-between-parvus-and-blackapps).

Comment: What would there be to discuss? And i never chat.